# Angular ViewChildren with nested children

Tags: angular, dom, viewchildren

The documentation for `ContentChildren` cleary states, that `QueryList` will not fetch anything inside child components. It doesn't state the same for `ViewChildren` though, so I am asking myself, if there is something I am doing wrong here.

**directive**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '.input-group'
})
export class InputGroupDirective {

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
    console.log(element); // <-- produces n results
  }
}
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
@ViewChildren( InputGroupDirective ) public inputGroup: QueryList<InputGroupDirective>;

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  console.log(this.inputGroup); // <- produces empty result
  console.log(document.querySelector('.input-group')); // <-produces n results
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<child></child>
```

**child.component.html**

```
<second-child></second-child>
```

**second.child.component.html**

```
<div class="input-group"></div>
```

Basically, what I need to do is to select the first `.input-group` in however nested children components. Any ideas?

Comment: ViewChild will only query items from components own template

Comment: So my only option would go vanilla JS?

Comment: you can do some tricks like parent: registerInputGroup(group){...} directive: costructor(parent: ParentComponent) {parent.registerInputGroup(this)}; if you like it better

Comment: or do something simmilar through service

Comment: thanks, Андрей! (getting a helping hand from someone in my native city is also a bonus! ;) )